# How do you print a warning in Dart

Tags: dart

Silly question, but the dart language tour nor a web search seems to come up with anything.

How do I print a warning when a particular method is used, analogous to `#warning` directive in C?

Comment: Do you mean print to standard error (stderr)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a warning from static analysis when a method is used, you should use the [`@Deprecated`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Deprecated-class.html) annotation.

For example:

```dart
@Deprecated('Call bar() instead')
void foo() {}
```